# (lldb) error when running on device but not simulator

Tags: xcode, swift, lldb

[Click here to see the screenshot of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VATxt.png)

I'm making a list application and I'm saving the array for the "list" that i wanna load when i open the app again.  **the weird thing is that i works on a simulator but not on a device**. (See the screenshot to understand)

```
        feedCells = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("feedCellsData") as? [String])!
```

**thats the line that it keeps crashing on.**

I've tried to change it so it's an optional value. But i can't find anything that seems to help..

Answer (score 1):

**First of all check that your device iOS version is iOS 8 or higher. If it is less than that then also use synchronize() after setting value to NSUserDefaults.**

You are forcefully unwrapping (using !) an optional value which you are getting from Down Casting (using as?).

You can also resolve this crash by adding a check for the value which you are fetching from the NSUserDefaults for not nil and then assign it to your feedCells var.

```
let cells = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("feedCellsData") as? [String]
if cells != nil {
    feedCells = cells
}
```

or

Make feedCells var an optional and remove "!" from the end of the line which is getting the error.

```
var feedCell : [String]?
feedCells = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("feedCellsData") as? [String]
```

Comment: This helped soooo much. There should be more people like you!

Comment: Accept & Up Vote the answer by clicking on the Right & Up Arrow button if it helped you.